# Is there any way I can get my cyan printed correctly?

Tags: color, print-design, cmyk, rgb

I am writing a book about indefinite integration and I want to use some color (especially in graphs). So, I figured I would use my favourite color, which is cyan (#00FFFF), and in the computer it shows up perfectly fine (using Latex). However, when I tested some pages in a local printer the color was nothing like the one I used. I searched the reason why and then I found out about the devastating truth of CMYK color based printing. As of this moment I am aware that the only way this color can exist in real life is by a light source emitting the exact wave length (I think 480nm). As a last effort I am here on this site asking if there is any way that I can get a very, VERY, close color to that particular cyan with a normal printer, or if there are any RGB based printers in this world to print my color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **no**.

You will not be able to achieve that overly vibrant blue in CMYK. You will need to determine an *actual* CMYK color you want. Note that **HEX is RGB**. Using hex values to pick color is *never* showing CMYK colors, its *always* showing RGB color.

So others have a reference....

[image]

It's just a limitation of the real world as opposed to digital. There's nothing you can do about it.

The *only* possible way to reproduce such a vibrant blue may be via a **spot color** and [Pantone Neon colors](https://www.pantone.com/products/graphics/pastels-neons-guide-coated-uncoated). Using spot colors typically increases printing costs, and depending upon *how* a color is used spot color *may* not be a viable option. I don't have the Pantone Neon color books, so I can't say for certain there's a Pantone color which would be closer to the RGB blue.

Comment: Yeah, the Pantone neon spot colours are probably the closest possible. However, even these depend on the light source under which they are viewed.  They're somewhat disappointing under ordinary indoor lighting. Look great in sunlight though, since it's the ultraviolet component in sunlight that makes them fluouresce.